# problemas para ver un PDF en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy usando el siguiente `código` para ver PDF en una nueva pestaña

```
<a target="_blank" href="{{asset('files/nombreDeTuPdf.pdf')}}">PDF</a>
```

El problema es que al momento de querer vizualizarlo en la nueva pestaña se queda en blanco y automáticamente se descarga el PDF.

Y lo que quiero es simplemente visualizarlo.

Comment: ¿Qué navegador?

Comment: en chrome y firefox

Comment: Dependiendo de tu navegador, la configuración de tu cliente de PDF y la configuración de las cabeceras que te devuelve el navegador, podrás o no evitar la descarga. @PedroOrtíz , mientras publicaba el comentario vi el tuyo. ¿Usas algún cliente de PDF? ¿PDF en otras webs las ves en el navegador o se descargan también?

Comment: ¿Has probado a usar un HTML que contenga una única etiqueta [`<embed>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/embed) ocupando el 100% de la ventana con un [tipo mime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) `application/pdf`? Eso debería forzar el uso de una aplicación externa para mostrar el contenido del PDF, aunque es mejor dejar elegir al navegador/usuario qué hacer con el archivo.

Comment: Antes usaba la opción de solo realizar descargas, pero el problema es que generaba muschos archivos, es por eso que estoy tratando de simplemente visualizar los PDF, apenas estoy realizando los cambios

Comment: Ya que no me has respondido a la pregunta más importante, haz el favor de decirme qué te devuelve `typeof navigator.mimeTypes['application/pdf']`. Si te devuelve `undefined` entonces tu navegador tiene deshabilitado el visor interno de PDF y, por lo tanto, siempre lo descargará.

Comment: no eh probado la etiqueta    <embed>

Comment: Para probarlo podrías usar `<embed src="documento.pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">Tu navegador no soporta mostrar archivos PDF, pulse <a href="documento.pdf">aquí</a> para descargarlo.</embed>`.

Comment: Lo eh probado, en chrome "se ha producido un error al cargar un documento PDF", y firefox ni me sale la ventana. Pero si puedo descargar el PDF en ambos navegadores.

Comment: Si pone que hubo un error al cargarlo es porque puede que no sea un PDF, ¿puedes abrirlo bien con otra aplicación? Y, lo más importante, en otras páginas donde tienen PDFs integrados en la página, ¿puedes verlos bien o te fuerza también la descarga? PD: No me dijiste lo que te sale con `typeof navigator.mimeTypes['application/pdf']` en la consola de javascript.

Comment: Otra aplicación?, no los puedo ver, me fuerza descargarlos. Con respecto a typeof navigator.mimeTypes['application/pdf']???

Comment: @OscarGarcia ya vi por que me marca error al cargar un document PDF, la razon es que no tengo guardado el PDF. Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es dar clic en "PDF" que esto genere y me muestre el PDF.

Comment: Para reproducir el error necesito que trabajes, si es posible, con uno ya generado. En cuanto a lo de JavaScript, lo necesito para saber si tu navegador tiene configurado un visor de documentos PDF instalado/activado.

Comment: Ya con este pude resolverlo con esto `public function show($id)
    {
        $data = Model::findOrFail($id);
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('elpdfamostrar.show', array('data' => $data));
        return $pdf->stream();
        
    }`  yo tenía `download` y lo cambíe a `loadView` con eso ya no descarga el PDF.

Comment: Redacta la respuesta, te daré un positivo por la resolución del problema. Entonces todo era problema de las cabeceras enviadas por el servidor. Deberías haber dicho que estabas haciendo uso de [DOMPDF Wrapper for Laravel 5](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf), nos hubieras ahorrado muchísimo tiempo y te hubiéramos dado (otra persona o yo) una respuesta mucho antes.

Comment: Una disculpa @OscarGarcia si estaba haciendo uso de DOMPDF, debo redactar mejor mis preguntas.